# GWT Double Click with addCellPreviewHandler works only in first page of table

Tags: java, gwt, pagination, double-click

I am using GWT 2.5 in a project and I had to add a double click event in a table, where I have to take both row and column, so, based on previous questions I created the following:

```
cellTable.addCellPreviewHandler(new CellPreviewEvent.Handler<BusStopsInfo>() {

           long lastClick=-1000;

           @Override
           public void onCellPreview(CellPreviewEvent<BusStopsInfo> event) {
               long clictAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
               if(event.getNativeEvent().getType().contains("click")){
                   if(clictAt-lastClick < 500) { // dblclick on 2 clicks detected within 500 ms
                       if (BrowserEvents.CLICK.equalsIgnoreCase(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
                            int columnHit = event.getColumn();
                            if (selectedItems != null){
                                selectedItems.clear();
                                selectionModel.clear();
                            }
                            selectedItems = new ArrayList<BusStopsInfo>();
                            Set<HasData<BusStopsInfo>> bsinfos = dataProvider.getDataDisplays();
                            Iterator<HasData<BusStopsInfo>> iter = bsinfos.iterator();
                            HasData<BusStopsInfo> bsinfo = iter.next();
                            Iterable<BusStopsInfo> iterbs = bsinfo.getVisibleItems();
                            int counterbs = 0;
                            for (BusStopsInfo bs : iterbs){
                                if (counterbs == event.getIndex()){
                                    selectedItems.add(bs);
                                    break;
                                }
                                counterbs++;
                            }
                            if (columnHit == 8){
                                edit_associations.click();
                            } else{
                                edit.click();
                            }
                       }

                   }
                   lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
               }
           }
       });
```

I also use pagination (SimplePager) in my tables, so, the above code is working fine in the first page of the table, but it doesn't work in other pages than first. Does anyone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified the error. Just in case it will help other people the error is here:

```
if (counterbs == event.getIndex()){
                                selectedItems.add(bs);
                                break;
                            }
```

replace with:

```
if (counterbs == (event.getIndex() - (pagertop.getPage()*pagertop.getPageSize()))){
                                selectedItems.add(bs);
                                break;
                            }
```

because dataProvider starts from 0 in each page.